# Issue on Clearing Set Drawing on Raphaël.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, raphael

Can you please take a look at [this sample](http://jsfiddle.net/Behseini/582Er/) and let me know how I can enable clearing a set of drawing on Raphaël?

```
var paper = Raphael('my-canvas', 500, 500);
var rect = paper.rect(100, 100, 100, 100);
var st = paper.set();
st.push(
    paper.circle(10, 10, 5),
    paper.circle(30, 10, 5)
);
st.attr({fill: "red"}); 

$(".clear").on("click",function(){
  st.clear();
});
```

Comment: It clears the set fine (which is different to removing the elements from the paper). Are you expecting to delete the elements as well in total ? If so, I would loop through the set (with a forEach) and element.remove()

Comment: Hi lan, thanks for reply. what I need is Deleting all circles in the set but keeping the other drawing like rectangle. I saw there is Set.clear() in the raphael documentation but it is not working here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to remove elements completely, you will probably want to use something like the element.remove() method. From a set, you can apply a forEach on it. So the code would look like...

```
var paper = Raphael('my-canvas', 500, 500);
var rect = paper.rect(100, 100, 100, 100);
var st = paper.set();
st.push(
    paper.circle(10, 10, 5),
    paper.circle(30, 10, 5)
);
st.attr({fill: "red"}); 

$(".clear").on("click",function(){
    st.forEach( function(el) {
        el.remove();
    });

// edit: or shorten it and just have st.remove()
});
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/582Er/2/)